# Binding datagrid and mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I'm having issues connecting to a mysql database and retrieving data to enter into a datagrid. I feel it has something to do with the `dataGrid1.DataContext = data;` syntax but i have no idea how to solve this, i think since it was wpf project it should be item source but looking at that I couldn't get that to work either. All that is being displayed when the program runs is a grey box.

C# code

```
 public void test()
    {
        string config = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=csharp";
        string query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM student1");

        MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(config);
        cn.Open();

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);

        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(data);
        dataGrid1.DataContext = data;


    }
```

XAML code

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xaml

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

Like following

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="dataGrid1"  />
```